# Copy and paste acording to number of another workbook row

Tags: excel, vba

i have two workbooks named "main" and "temp" . in workbook "temp" i have 2 sheets.  i wanna write a macro that in a loop from A1 TO A1000, search cell A(x,1) VALUE  from workbook "main" in workbook"temp" sheet"1" and if find it , then copy and paste entire row in workbook"temp" sheet"2".   i write below code. but two  problem exsits:

1- i wanna copy the  the entire row found in workbook "temp" sheet1 in sheet 2 according to workbook "main" row number not workbook"temp" row number. i mean if text:book is in A(1,1) cell in workbook "main" and found it in A(9,1) in workbook"temp".sheet1 copy its entire row and paste it in  sheet2 in row 1 not row 9.

2-i write macro in workbook"temp" and have a button to run this macro- but when i am in sheet2 macro don't work well but when i am in sheet1 its works well.

please help me find problems...thanks

```
Sub sorting()
Dim coname As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim cell As Range

For counter = 1 To 1000
        coname = Workbooks("main").Worksheets("statics").Cells(counter, 1)
        With Workbooks("temp").Worksheets(1)
            For Each cell In Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))
              If cell.Value = coname Then
               Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("temp").Sheets(2).Rows(cell.Row)
               End If
            Next cell
        End With
Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1.

I would change `coname` to be a `Range` data type (`Dim coname As Range`) and then slightly change your code like so:

```
If cell.Value = coname.Value Then
    coname.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Workbooks("temp").Sheets(2).cell
End If
```

By changing the datatype, we can now refer to the correct row (on the correct sheet) using the [EntireRow property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow) of the `coname` Range object.

Previously you were getting the wrong row because your source data was using the `Cell.Row` property to get the row to copy from, but that is your destination reference, so changing it to `coname` now points the source data to the right range.

### 2.

Use explicit qualification to your workbook/worksheets! Currently the issue of where you call the code from is due to this line: `For Each cell In Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))`.

Because you haven't lead the `Range()` reference with a `.`, it's not making use of the `With` statement it's within! So it translates to `ActiveSheet.Range("A1"...)`. Put a `.` in front of Range to use your `With` statement and it will be `Workbooks("temp").Worksheets(1).Range("A1"...)`.

After that it won't matter where/how you call the code, it will always refer to the correct sheet!

Answer (score 1):

### Three Sheets in Play

- Carefully adjust the constants to fit your needs.
- Especially take care of `srcLastColumn` which wasn't mentioned in
  your question. You don't want to copy the whole range, just the range
  containing values.
- The complete code goes into a standard module (e.g. `Module1`).

What the code **emulates** would be something like the following:

- In the `Main` Worksheet loops through a column and reads the values row
  by row.
- It compares each of the value with each of the values in a column in
  the `Source` Worksheet.
- If it finds a match it writes the complete row containing values from
  `Source` Worksheet to the same row as the row of `Main` Worksheet,
  but to the row in `Target` Worksheet.
- Then it stops searching and goes to the next row in `Main` Worksheet.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sorting()

    Const mFirst As String = "A1"         ' First Cell in Main or Target
    Const mWbName As String = "main.xlsx" ' The workbook has to be open.
    Const mWsName As String = "statics"

    Const srcNameOrIndex As Variant = 1   ' It is safer to use the Sheet Name.
    Const srcFirst As String = "A1"       ' First Cell in Source
    Const srcLastColumn As Long = 5       ' !!! Source Last Column !!!

    Const tgtNameOrIndex As Variant = 2   ' It is safer to use the Sheet Name.

    ' Write values from Main and Source Worksheets to Main and Source Arrays.
    Dim mn As Worksheet: Set mn = Workbooks(mWbName).Worksheets(mWsName)
    Dim Main As Variant     ' Main Array
    Main = getColumn(mn, mn.Range(mFirst).Column, mn.Range(mFirst).Row)
    If IsEmpty(Main) Then Exit Sub
    Dim src As Worksheet: Set src = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcNameOrIndex)
    Dim Source As Variant   ' Source Array
    Source = getColumn(src, src.Range(srcFirst).Column, src.Range(srcFirst).Row)
    If IsEmpty(Source) Then Exit Sub
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = src.Range(srcFirst).Resize(UBound(Source), _
                        srcLastColumn - src.Range(srcFirst).Column + 1)
    Source = rng: Set rng = Nothing

    ' Write values from Source Array to Target Array.
    Dim ubM As Long: ubM = UBound(Main)
    Dim ubS1 As Long: ubS1 = UBound(Source)
    Dim ubS2 As Long: ubS2 = UBound(Source, 2)
    Dim Target As Variant   ' Target Array
    ReDim Target(1 To ubM, 1 To ubS2)
    Dim i As Long, k As Long, l As Long, Criteria As String
    For i = 1 To ubM
        Criteria = Main(i, 1)
        For k = 1 To ubS1
            If Source(k, 1) = Criteria Then
               For l = 1 To ubS2
                   Target(i, l) = Source(k, l)
               Next l
               Exit For
            End If
        Next k
    Next i

    ' Write values from Target Array to Target Worksheet.
    Dim tgt As Worksheet: Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtNameOrIndex)
    tgt.Range(mFirst).Resize(ubM, ubS2) = Target

    ' Inform user.
    MsgBox "Data successfully transfered.", vbInformation, "Success"
    ' If you don't see this message, nothing has happened.

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Writes the values of a one-column range to a 2D one-based      '
'               one-column or one-row array.                                   '
' Returns:      A 2D one-based one-column or one-row array.                    '
' Remarks:      The cells below the column range have to be empty.             '
'               If an error occurs the function will return an empty variant.  '
'               Therefore its result can be tested with "IsEmpty".             '
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function getColumn(Sheet As Worksheet, ByVal AnyColumn As Variant, _
                   Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1, _
                   Optional ByVal transposeResult As Boolean = False, _
                   Optional ByVal showMessages As Boolean = False) As Variant
    Const Proc As String = "getColumn"
    On Error GoTo cleanError
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheet.Columns(AnyColumn).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    If rng.Row < FirstRow Then Exit Function
    Set rng = Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(FirstRow, AnyColumn), rng)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Not transposeResult Then
            getColumn = rng
        Else
            getColumn = Application.Transpose(rng)
        End If
    End If
    Exit Function
cleanError:
    If showMessages Then
        MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
             & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
               , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```